# How to apply variational calculus to probability density functions with constraints?

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, stochastic-calculus, calculus-of-variations, malliavin-calculus

I would like to use variational calculus to find the probability density function $p(x)$ that maximizes the tail probability, i.e., I would like to find

\begin{equation}
\max_{p(x)} \int_K^\infty p(x) \mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}

where $K>0$. We are also given that the random variable $X$ is nonnegative and has expected value $\mu$. *Generalized functions are permitted*. I know the answer and a solution method but I wanted to figure out an alternative path that uses variational calculus. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I formulated the problem as

\begin{align}
\max_{p(x)} &\int_K^\infty p(x) \mathrm{d}x \\\\
\mathrm{s.t.}  &\int_{-\infty}^\infty xp(x) \mathrm{d}x = \mu\\\\
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) \mathrm{d}x = 1 \\\\
& p(x) \geq 0.
\end{align}

To get rid of the last constraint, I reformulated the problem as

\begin{align}
\max_{f(x)} &\int_K^\infty (f(x))^2 \mathrm{u}(x-K)\mathrm{d}x \\\\
\mathrm{s.t.}  &\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(f(x))^2 \mathrm{u}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \mu\\\\
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x))^2 \mathrm{u}(x)\mathrm{d}x = 1,
\end{align}
where I've made the subtitution $p(x) = (f(x))^2\mathrm{u}(x)$ and $\mathrm{u}(\cdot)$ is the unit step function
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{u}(x):={\begin{cases}1,&x\geq 0\\\\0,&x< 0\end{cases}}.
\end{equation}
This substitution for $p(x)$ is meant to accomplish two things: take into account that $p(x)$ is nonnegative for all $x$ (because it is a PDF) and to acknowledge the fact that $X$ is nonnegative.

At this point, I tried using Lagrange multipliers but it didn't lead to anything fruitful. I'm guessing that at some point the fact that the PDF should vanish at $\pm \infty$ might help. I'm also guessing that instead of making this substitution for $p(x)$, I can instead use a Lagrange multiplier that isn't constant. In any case, I'm stuck. Again, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A probability distribution $p(x)$ is a [Cadlag function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g), don't know for sure if [Variational Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) apply to discontinuous functions: at least for random processes that don't fulfill the requirements to have [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) as valid it were invented the [Ito's Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus) (among others), which variational counterpart its [Maliavin Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malliavin_calculus), last two quite advanced math, unfortunately I cannot help you (due the links, this were to long for a comment).

But seeing the problem you are working on, maybe an easy alternative could be done if the probability distributions are continuous: see the example of how is proved that the Gaussian Distribution is the [Maximum Entropy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Continuous_case) for a continuous process with finite mean and variance - maybe also just through [Laplace multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) you could also solve your question.

Sorry for not being more useful.